# Passwords like this $5$rounds=5000$/mLhDmcPo

Tags: mysql, passwords, command-line-interface

How can I create a password in mysql that looks like this $5$rounds=5000$/mLhDmcPoT3lHt4T$IIHC08bghQ0me8m.kMFxOMxfz/g1CW1TglF3WE9zVpA ?

I have a linux shell script that used md5 to generate passwords. The md5 function is in a mysql statement which updates a mysql database. I now need to generate passwords that dovecot 2.2.27 (c0f36b0) can verify. The script asks for a username and then updates the database with the new password. Dovecot verifies pop3 and imap access using this database. I tried replacing the md5 function with sha2 and it does generate a password and update the database but the inserted password does not contain the $5$rounds business.

here is the dovecot config data:

default_pass_scheme = SHA256-CRYPT

Here is the code snippet:
modPass () {

```
    echo ""
    echo "Modifying email ${EMAIL}."
    getInput "Enter new password: " pw
    NEWPASS="${ANSWER}"
    DOMAINID=`${DBCON} "SELECT id FROM ${DATABASE}.virtual_users WHERE email = '${EMAIL}';"`
    ${DBCON} "USE ${DATABASE}; UPDATE virtual_users SET password = SHA2('${NEWPASS}', 256) WHERE virtual_users.id = '${DOMAINID}';"
    echo ""
    echo "Password for account ${EMAIL} modified"
```

Let me know if I need to supply more details. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Please explain the rules for calculating the password

Answer (score 0):

Since there were no responses from stackoverflow readers before I had to take the email server live I changed all the password types to md5. md5 is not the best solution but according to stackoverflow it seems to be the only solution.